# Spotify API - autocomplete search results are null

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, spotify

Playing with Spotify API - I would like to use jQuery to autocomplete a field with artists as I type. So far I'm working with the following:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text-box" placeholder="Enter Artist" id="artist-input">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#artist-input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                type: "artist",
                limit: 3,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                format: "json",
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.artists, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#artist-input").val(ui.item.value);
        window.location.href = "#" + ui.item.value;
    },
});

});
```

Running this, results:

```
functions.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

So my question is do I need to do some sort of authentication before this process can run? My thought process is that it's making the call but it's returning as null, and I'm missing an extra step...

Here is a codepen with this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGKLpj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are using is structured a bit differently. It is `data.artists.items`instead of `data.artists`. If you loop over the right attribute, it works just fine.

Check out this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaXvob

Note: it helps out to just `console.log(data);` sometimes to see if the json structure matches that what you think it is.

Comment: Ah. Ok thanks! A lot of the answers that I referred to on here were still using the deprecated API http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json etc, so it was in the back of my mind if the data attribute was off.